# "NLB ARN is malformed" when create VPC link for AWS APIGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-vpc, aws-elb

I followed the tutorial to create a VPC link to my private elb balancer.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-api-with-vpclink-cli.html

But it failed, and got an error message "statusMessage": "NLB ARN is malformed".

I do find the ELB with same ARN by elbv2 cli, so the ARN must be a legal one...

I can't find document to solve the problem.
anyone can help me? thank you.

what i did is as following.

```
$ aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-arns arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:846239845603:loadbalancer/app/v2-api-balancer/db49ab0ecaef1de8

{
"LoadBalancers": [
{
"Scheme": "internal",
"SecurityGroups": [
"sg-9282b8f4"
],
"LoadBalancerArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:846239845603:loadbalancer/app/v2-api-balancer/db49ab0ecaef1de8",
"State": {
"Code": "active"
},
"CreatedTime": "2017-10-18T04:27:28.780Z",
"VpcId": "vpc-dbe3f2be",
"DNSName": "internal-v2-api-balancer-988454399.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com",
"AvailabilityZones": [
{
"SubnetId": "subnet-7642062e",
"ZoneName": "ap-northeast-1c"
},
{
"SubnetId": "subnet-c454fa8d",
"ZoneName": "ap-northeast-1b"
}
],
"IpAddressType": "ipv4",
"Type": "application",
"LoadBalancerName": "v2-api-balancer",
"CanonicalHostedZoneId": "Z14GRHDCWA56QT"
}
]
}
```

---

```
$ aws apigateway create-vpc-link \ 
--name my-test-vpc-link-1 \
--target-arns "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:846239845603:loadbalancer/app/v2-api-balancer/db49ab0ecaef1de8" 

{
"name": "my-test-vpc-link-1",
"targetArns": [
"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:846239845603:loadbalancer/app/v2-api-balancer/db49ab0ecaef1de8"
],
"id": "7eexgn",
"status": "PENDING"
}
```

---

```
$ aws apigateway get-vpc-link --vpc-link-id 7eexgn

{
"id": "7eexgn",
"targetArns": [
"arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-1:846239845603:loadbalancer/app/v2-api-balancer/db49ab0ecaef1de8"
],
"status": "FAILED",
"name": "my-test-vpc-link-1",
"statusMessage": "NLB ARN is malformed"
}
```

---

Comment: Note the string `/app/` in the ARN.  That is an *Application* Load Balancer.  A *Network* Load Balancer would have `/net/` here.

Comment: I was also mistakenly using an application load balancer (Terraform default) and seeing this error message. It's definitely end user error but the error message could also be better.

Answer (score 11):

VPC Links must be to a *network* LB. Looks like you are trying to use an application LB.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-nlb-for-vpclink-using-console.html