# Cannot create API Management VPC Link in AWS Console

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I'm failing to add a VPC Link to my API Gateway that will link to my application load balancer.  The symptom in the AWS Console is that the dropdown box for **Target NLB** is empty.  If I attempt to force the issue via the AWS CLI, an entry is created; but the status says `NLB ARN is malformed`.

I've verified the following:

- My application load balancer is in the same account and region as my API Gateway.
- My user account has admin privileges.  I created and added the recommended policy just in case I was missing something.
- The NLB ARN was copied directly from the application load balancer page for the AWS CLI creation scenario.
- I can invoke my API directly on the ECS instance (it has a public IP for now).
- I can invoke my API through the application load balancer public IP.

Possible quirks with my configuration:

- My application load balancer has a security group which limits access to a narrow range of IPs.  I didn't think this would matter since VPC links are suppose to connect with the private DNS.
- My ECS instance has private DNS enabled.
- My ECS uses EC2 launch type, not Fargate.

Comment: After creating this question, a link to the right referenced a related question that may be the source of my headache.  I configured an Application Load Balancer (ALB).  But apparently a Network Load Balancer (NLB) is required.  I'll give that a shot and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as suggested in [a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170258/nlb-arn-is-malformed-when-create-vpc-link-for-aws-apigateway?rq=1), my problem stems from initially creating an ALB (**Application** Load Balancer) rather than an NLB (**Network** Load Balancer).  Once I had an NLB configured properly, I was able to configure the VPC Link as described in the AWS documentation.